# Proposition 4.4.12 Pederson Analysis Now, Why does this operator commute?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, functional-calculus

Here is the proposition:

[image]

[image]

The part I'm not understanding is (as usual with most of Pederson's proofs) the last implication.    The last equality just seems to imply that $S$ commutes with the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^n (T^{*})^n}{n!}$$ in the limit.  I don't see how this implies that $S$ nessiarily commutes with $T^{*}$.  Even if $S$ commuted with a finite partial sum of the power series, I don't see how this would imply what he's claiming is true.

Comment: Hint: since $e^{-\lambda T^\ast}Se^{\lambda T^\ast} = S$, that is, $Se^{\lambda T^\ast} = e^{\lambda T^\ast}S$, for all $\lambda$, you can take derivatives of both sides of the equation above with respect to $\lambda$.